# Classic asp convert varchar to int in SQL query using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, sql-server-2014

I am updating a legacy site that uses classic asp and used to use SQL Server 2003. The `sortorder` column is stored as `varchar`.

The following used to convert the `varchar` column to an `int` that could then be sorted in in the output (1-20 numerically). Now the returned records go from "1" to "10" then "11" etc. It is still treating them as `varchar`.

Do I need to convert in the classic asp file to something new for SQL Server 2014? I have tried cast, and parse.

```
RQ="Select *, convert(int, sortorder) from table Where theid=1 order by sortorder"
Set rs = Connect.Execute(Rq)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide. I have checked the answers here, but can't find anything for newer SQL Server database with Classic ASP.

Comment: You need to also do a conversion in the `ORDER BY` clause - otherwise it's ordering **as strings** (as you see it happening). But really: you should **fix the bad DB design** in the first place to avoid all this messy conversion in the first place!

Comment: And BTW: there never was a SQL Server **2003** version - we had 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014

Comment: Marc, thank you for correct answer and speed.  Guess I was on 2003.  

RQ="Select * from table Where CompanyID=1 order by convert(int, sortorder)"

Site has changed since last time I was here.  I gave you an up arrow, don't see a solved button to give you credit though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be doing the conversion to `INT` in your `ORDER BY` clause so that it gets sorted properly:

```
RQ = "Select * from table Where theid=1 order by convert(int, sortorder)"
Set rs = Connect.Execute(Rq)
```

Just converting in the list of columns of the `SELECT` doesn't help ...

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29108549/692942) provided by [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) is spot on. Just wanted to elaborate on how I deal with casting in SQL queries to avoid these types of issues.

So you don't have to specify `CONVERT(INT, sortorder)` multiple times a simple wrapper around your query makes it easier to work with.

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM (
    -- List only the columns required.
    SELECT [col1], [col2], ... , CONVERT(INT, sortorder) [sortorder] 
    FROM [table]
    WHERE [theid] = 1
) t
ORDER BY t.sortorder
```

Ideally though as [@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108305/classic-asp-convert-varchar-to-int-in-sql-query-using-sql-server-2014#comment46446278_29108305) better database design would negate the need for this type of solution.

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart.  I did what @marc_s suggested and spent the rest of the afternoon learning how to convert the column type to int.  For any other newbies...after copying the table for back up
`/*alter a data type need null or not null*/

ALTER TABLE [tablename]
ALTER COLUMN sortorder int null`

thanks again everyone. works perfect.